# Optimisation reproduces initial values?

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to maximize the following function with `optimx` in R

```
#Initial Parameter Values
beta1=0.5
beta2=0.5
lambda1=0.5
lambda2=0.5
delta=5

loglik=function(par) {sum(log(lambda1*PDF1+lambda2*PDF2))+delta*(lambda1+lambda2-1)}

G2=optimx(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,2),fn=loglik,gr=NULL, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, hessian=FALSE)
```

But every time the optimization reproduces the initial values that I provide to the system, for e.g this is the response I get to the optimization using the above mentioned initial values.

```
             p1  p2  p3  p4 p5    value fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1 kkt2
Nelder-Mead 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5  2 5144.569      6     NA    NA        0 TRUE   NA
BFGS        0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5  2 5144.569      1      1    NA        0 TRUE   NA
            xtimes
Nelder-Mead      0
BFGS             0
```

Can anyone please tell whats going on?

Comment: What is `PDF1` and `PDF2`?

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* I switched out `optimx` for the built in `optim` in my answer.  This does not change the content.  I also switched out your `PDF1` and `PDF2` in the function body for `beta1` and `beta2` on a hunch about your intent.

You're misunderstanding how `optimx`, and honestly, functions, work.

Here's your definition of `loglik`

```
loglik <- function(par) {
  sum(log(lambda1*beata1 + lambda2*beta2)) + delta*(lambda1 + lambda2 - 1)
}
```

Now watch

```
> loglik(1)
[1] -0.6931472
> loglik(2)
[1] -0.6931472
> loglik("I like cats.")
[1] -0.6931472
```

You haven't so much defined a function, but a constant.  You can see this by observing that the function you defined makes no reference to its argument `par`.  Instead, it ignores `par` and simply looks up the variables it contains in its enclosing environment.

You most likely meant to do this

```
loglik <- function(par) {
  sum(log(par[3]*par[1] + par[4]*par[2])) + par[5]*(par[3] + par[4] - 1)
}
```

After which the optimization works as intended

```
optim(c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,2), fn=loglik, gr=NULL, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf, hessian=FALSE)
$par
[1]  0.6466066  0.8102440 -0.2802594  0.2236580  2.6381565

$value
[1] -40.91057

$counts
function gradient 
     501       NA 

$convergence
[1] 1
```

A convergence code of `1` **does not** indicate convergence

> 1
>   indicates that the iteration limit maxit had been reached.

Indeed, there are plenty of warnings

```
warnings()
1: In log(par[3] * par[1] + par[4] * par[2]) : NaNs produced
2: In log(par[3] * par[1] + par[4] * par[2]) : NaNs produced
```

You'll have to sort that out, I don't know what you are actually trying to accomplish with this call.

> Thank you, But the problem is PDF1 and PDF2 are also functions defined by
>
> PDF1=function(beta1) {BiCopPDF(u,v,par=abs(beta1),family=5)}
>
> and
>
> PDF2=function(beta2) {BiCopPDF(u,v,par=beta2,family=3)}
>
> How do I manage that?

You will have to call into `PDF1` and `PDF2` *within* the function you are optimizing.  If I understand correctly, this would result in something like:

```
loglik <- function(par) {
  sum(log( par[3]*PDF1(par[1]) + par[4]*PDF2(par[2]) )) + par[5]*(par[3] + par[4] - 1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But the problem is PDF1 and PDF2 are also functions defined PDF1=function(beta1) {BiCopPDF(u,v,par=abs(beta1),family=5)}
PDF2=function(beta2) {BiCopPDF(u,v,par=beta2,family=3)}
How do I manage that?

Comment: 1) Please add these details to the statement of the question.  2) You added another ambiguity, what are u and v supposed to be inside of your loglik? 3) Given that the PDF's are functions, and you did not *call* them in your loglik function, I really think your understanding of functions in `R` is too deficient to be doing something this complicated.  I would recommend starting small, reading a tutorial on how functions work, and then coming back to this.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. By the way the functions PDF1 and PDF2 had already been called. But given the size of the program, I had to break it into different fractions.

Comment: If `beta1` and `beta2` are parameters that are getting optimized, then it is not sufficient to call `PDF1` and `PDF2` once.  You must call them *within* the function being optimized.  I'll add this into my answer.

Comment: If you have an email and are willing to share I can share the problem. Other wise it is difficult for you to understand what I am doing. Thanks

Comment: here is the function                                                                                                                                                   loglik=function(par) {sum(log(dnorm(inrspot,mean=0.0002797,sd=0.0000092567)))+sum(log(dnorm(ndf1m,mean=0.000483,sd=0.00003181)))+
sum(log(par[3]*PDF1(par[1])+par[4]*PDF2(par[2])))+par[5]*(par[3]+par[4]-1)}                                                                                                    athis is a likelihood function with three parts(MLE in stages)  I solved pt I & II. Having problems with third part

Comment: Are the parameters you explicitly supplied to `dnorm` the result of an optimization?  You should be aware that the maximizer of a sum is *not* the sum of the maximizers, unless the summands are completely independent.